# What would be the most efficient mechanism to implement branching choices?

Tags: game-design

I am developing a Windows game engine that will let you create games styled like *"Phoenix Wright: Ace Attorney"*. I have finished developing the data entry parts (evidence, profiles, animations, etc.), and now I am going to create the scene editor. With this editor, you can create courtroom scenes.

I am having a particular game-flow design problem with "choice branches", where the player can select an option from many, and something will happen depending on the choice. How should I design such thing? I have no problems creating a linear flow (action, action, action, etc.), but I am confused by things like cross-examination or chatting involve branching choices (action; if did something, do this; if did something else, do that; etc.).

What would be the most efficient mechanism to organize such branches for my design, in the simplest way for the user to understand? I don't want to make it too complex for the user to make a game with the engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Finite State Machine would seem to fit this type of flow.  Users can easily understand a FSM with very little explanation.  You might organize individual states such that they have entry and exit events.  For instance when you enter the state, graphics/text xyz are displayed.

The exit conditions for each state are simply the choices that the user can choose from.  Based on the choice made, you enter a new state or possibly loop back to the existing state.
[image: Basic Finite State Machine]

Comment: So this is like, say, making a text-based game with Flash keyframes (as in, if choice A, go to keyframe 30, if choice B, go to keyframe 31)?

Comment: I'm not sure what question you are asking exactly.  Yes, you could let the states be specific keyframes.